# function to zero array elements

Tags: c, arrays, function

I wrote this code that check suduko answers and for some reason my the array which I sum the squares of the suduko into is all zeros in the functions I zero it in, but when I use it in my check function it isn't all zeros

if i move the exact same code of my array zeroing function to my other function and run it it works.
(i am using c99, dont know if it matters)

Any ideas?

```
int squareSum[5][5];
//set array elements to zero
setArrayToZero(squareSize, squareSize, squareSum);
/*for(int i = 0; i<squareSize; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<squareSize; j++)
        squareSum[i][j] = 0;
}*/
printf("%d, %d\n%d, %d\n\n", squareSum[0][0], squareSum[0][1], squareSum[1][0], squareSum[1][1]);
```

[this is the array is case squareSize is two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmKR2.png)
if i add the for in the comments in, the array isall zeros, and as you can see below its the exact same as the function i call.

```
void setArrayToZero(int rows, int columns, int array[][columns]){
for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j<columns; j++)
        array[i][j] = 0;\\if i print the array in function its all zeros.
```

p.s
i know i am using only part of the array, its an assignment from the university and we are not allowed to use malloc so i am creating the array at thier max size - 25.

thank you in advance.

full c file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L00L3lvMYNcaz2SswEBnmi9KO-79oaHg

all the print functions, are part of the demand for the course (for auto checking)

Comment: What is the value of `squareSize` at the calling site?

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://www.ideone.com/sGH8w0)

Answer (score 3):

> A reference to an object of type array-of-T which appears in an
> expression decays (with three exceptions) into a pointer to its first
> element; the type of the resultant pointer is pointer-to-T.

So that means in this case also (this is not one of those 3 exceptions) your passed array will decay into pointers and *now you change to the array by accessing the address, that's why it will be retained in the callee function.*

You are doing it the right way. The problem is not with passing or anything. Maybe you are accessing it wrong or maybe you didn't initialize it properly. But there is nothing wrong with the zeroing out.

And for further information **everything is pass by value in C**. There is nothing called pass by reference in C. The pointer workings makes us think that there is something called pass by reference in C but that's not the case, here also pointer variables are copied into some local variable in the called function. but as we have those addresses in the called function and we access them and make changes - they retain in callee function.

---

#### After OP posted the sample code

Apaprt from the overly complicated sudoku checking logic there is much more going wrong.

I will just mention the printing part.

In C elements of 2d-arrays are stored sequentially. When we pass the 2d array to the function we need to specify the column size so that we can determine the correct element.

Suppose you want to access `a[4][7]` in `10x13` array. The element would be at the address `&a[0][0]+4*13+7`. That's why the `column` part is passed as an argument.

Now what you did :

```
int squareSum[5][5], rowColSum[25][2];
//set arrays elements to zero
setArrayToZero(size, 2, rowColSum);
setArrayToZero(squareSize, squareSize, squareSum);
```

The first one is alright. As there are 2 columns. But what about the second one?
here you are telling the function that you are passing an array with column `size = 2` but that is not the case. It is still the 2d array with 5 columns.

That's where you had the problem. Suppose you initialize the array with `10,21,34,14`

Suppose `grid` is `5x5` array (in your case it's 25x25)
grid[5][5] array

And you do this

```
for(int i = 0; i<squareSize; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j<squareSize; j++)
     scanf("%d",&grid[i][j]);

/*
Input is 13 17 19 23
*/


 +-----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+--...\
 |  0  |  1  |  2  |   3  |   4 |  5  |  6  |  7 |  8 |  9 |  
 +-----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+--...\
/      \     \                  /      \     \
  13      17                       19     23
```

Now you access it like this

You pass it to the function with this call `print2dArray(int row, int col, int g[][col])`

You call like this  `print2dArray(2,2,grid);``
...

```
for(int i = 0; i<row; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j<col; j++)
     printf("%d",&grid[i][j]);
```

Now you will print these elements `(i) : denotes the order`

```
+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+--...\
|  0  |  1  |  2  |   3  |   4 |  5  |  6  |  7 |  8 |  9 |  
+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+--...\
/      \     \  ^    ^        /      \     \
 13      17     |    |            19     23
 (1)    (2)    (3)  (4)
```

Similarly, those were uninitialized in your case. That's why you got those weird results. You were initializing some elements of the 2d array to `0` but when you are reading the array then you were accessing some different elements. That's why the wrong result.

Solution for this:

- Call `int correctSum = inputGrid(squareSize, 25, grid);` Note that it should be `squareSize`. Accordingly change the storage of `digitsCounter` in `inputGrid`.
- The function signature for `inputGrid` would be  `inputGrid(size, col, grid[][col]);`
- Same when calling the

  `setArrayToZero(size, 2, rowColSum);` and
  `setArrayToZero(squareSize, 5, squareSum);`

I simply didn't check the logic. The answer deals with explaining the printing behavior of the 2d array.

Comment: @sagy101.: Can you post the full code? Or how you call it and how you check it?

Comment: sure tnx, added full code to the main post at the end

Comment: @sagy101.: Sorry for the late reply. This explains the printing behavior. But try to test the sudoku logic and simplify it a bit.